# How to detect a concurrrent change of value in the data which are modified in a JSF page?

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, concurrency

A JSF page contains a list of bank accounts.

When the user clicks on the id of an account, a new page is displayed which allows to withdraw some money from the account. This new page has a parameter view of type Account with a converter to convert the id into an Account. The page displays information on the account and ask the amount to withdraw.

When the user submit the form to withdraw some money, the new balance is registered in the database with a stateless EJB (with a merge).

I would like to detect if another user modify the same account at the same moment but it is impossible because there is never an OptimisticLockException.

The explanation: if the version number (attribute annotated with @Version) is 5 at the begining, and if another user change the balance just after and submit the form right away, the version number is incremented to 6. I thought the first user would have an OptimisticLockException but it is not the case. Indeed, when the first user submits the form to change the balance, the form is rebuild on the server and the acccount is read again with the new version number equal to 6 and the version number change is not detected when the new balance is registered in the database with a merge (followed by a commit) in the EJB.

So the first user is not aware that another user changed the value of the balance while he was working on the account. It could be a problem.

How could I do to detect the concurrent change? Should I keep the version number in the code and compare with the version number just before the merge (with a pessimistic lock!)? Is there another better way to do that? Perhaps I have to change the structure of my pages?

My code (sorry, it's in French):

JSF page that modify an account (add or withdraw money):

```
<ui:composition template="./template.xhtml">

  <ui:param 
    name="soustitre" 
    value="Ajouter/retirer de l'argent sur le compte de 
           #{mouvementBean.compteBancaire.nom}"/>

  <ui:define name="metadata">
    <f:metadata>
      <f:viewParam name='id' value='#{mouvementBean.compteBancaire}'
                   converter='#{modifierBean.converter}' />
    </f:metadata>
  </ui:define>

  <ui:define name="content">
    <f:phaseListener type="jsf.util.DebugPhaseListener"/>
    <h1>Ajouter/enlever de l'argent sur le compte de  
        #{mouvementBean.compteBancaire.nom}</h1>
    <h:form id="form">
      <h3>Type mouvement :</h3>
      <h:selectOneRadio 
        id='typeMouvement'
        value='#{mouvementBean.typeMouvement}'
        required='true'
        layout='pageDirection'
        requiredMessage="Vous devez dire s'il s'agit d'un ajout ou d'un retrait">
        <f:selectItem itemValue="ajout"
                      itemLabel="Ajout"/>
        <f:selectItem itemValue="retrait"
                      itemLabel="Retrait"/>
      </h:selectOneRadio>
      <h:message for="typeMouvement"/>
      <h3>Montant de la sommme</h3>
      <h:inputText 
        id="montant" value='#{mouvementBean.montant}' required='true'
        requiredMessage="Le montant doit être un nombre entier positif"/>
      <h:message for="montant"/>
      <br/><br/>
      <h:commandButton action="#{mouvementBean.sauvegarder()}" 
                       value="Enregistrer"/>
    </h:form>

  </ui:define>

</ui:composition>
```

The backing bean for the page:

```
Named(value = "mouvementBean")
@ViewScoped
public class MouvementBean implements Serializable {

  @EJB
  private GestionnaireDeCompteBancaire gestionnaireDeCompteBancaire;

  private CompteBancaire compteBancaire;
  private String typeMouvement;
  @Min(value = 1, message = "Le montant doit être un entier positif")
  private int montant;

  public CompteBancaire getCompteBancaire() {
    return compteBancaire;
  }

  public void setCompteBancaire(CompteBancaire compteBancaire) {
    this.compteBancaire = compteBancaire;
  }

  public String getTypeMouvement() {
    return typeMouvement;
  }

  public void setTypeMouvement(String typeMouvement) {
    this.typeMouvement = typeMouvement;
  }

  public int getMontant() {
    return montant;
  }

  public void setMontant(int montant) {
    this.montant = montant;
  }

  public String sauvegarder() {
    // Enregistre le mouvement dans l'entité
    switch (typeMouvement) {
    case "ajout":
      compteBancaire.deposer(montant);
      break;
    case "retrait":
      try {
        compteBancaire.retirer(montant);
      } catch (CompteException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MouvementBean.class.getName()).log(Level.WARNING, null, ex);
        Util.messageErreur("Solde insuffisant sur le compte", 
              "Solde insuffisant sur le compte de " + compteBancaire.getNom(), 
              "form:montant");
        return null;
      }
      break;
    }
    // Enregistre dans la base de données
    gestionnaireDeCompteBancaire.modifierCompte(compteBancaire);
    // Message de succès
    Util.addFlashInfoMessage(typeMouvement + " de " + montant + " effectué pour "
        + compteBancaire.getNom());
    return "listeComptes?faces-redirect=true";
  }
}
```

The converter (in another backing bean ModifierBean):

```
public Converter getConverter() {
  return new Converter() {
    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, 
          String value) {
      // Pour faire des tests pour la concurrence
      CompteBancaire c = 
            gestionnaireDeCompteBancaire.getById(Long.parseLong(value));
      System.out.println("Dans le convertisseur à la fin de getAsObject " + c);
    return c;
//        return gestionnaireDeCompteBancaire.getById(Long.parseLong(value));
  }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, 
          Object value) {
      return ((CompteBancaire)value).getId().toString();
    }
  };
}
```

The link toward the page in the list of all the accounts:

```
        <p:dataTable value="#{listeManagedBean.comptes}" var="item"
                     paginator="true" rows="5"
                     rowsPerPageTemplate="2,5,10,20">
          <p:column filterBy="#{item.id}" filterMatchMode="exact"
                    sortBy="#{item.id}"
                    style="width: 5%; text-align: center;">
            <f:facet name="header">
              <h:outputText value="Id"/>
            </f:facet>
            <h:link outcome="mouvement" value="#{item.id}">
              <f:param name="id" value="#{item.id}"/>
            </h:link>
          </p:column>
```

Comment: Please provide more details. What JPA provider do you use? How and where do you enforce optimistic locking?

Comment: I don't enforce optimistic locking; JPA has a default optimistic locking when a merge is done. If the entity would not be read again for the first user, the version number would not be the same as the version number of the database (because of the update made by the other user) and the merge would throw an OptimisticLockException.

Comment: By default Eclipselink does not enforce optimistic locking. On the contrary it assumes that the application itself manages concurrency issues. So you have ended up with no locking policy. As said in the [Understanding Eclipselink](http://eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/concepts/entities007.htm#BGBBDDIJ), "By default, the EclipseLink persistence provider assumes that the application is 
responsible for data consistency"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is:

> when the first user submits the form to change the balance, the form is rebuild on the server and the acccount is read again with the new version number equal to 6

The account should be loaded / reloaded **only**

> When the user clicks on the id of an account, a new page is displayed which allows to withdraw some money from the account

And not when

> user submits the form to change the balance

You should use at least a @ViewScoped bean to maintain the account loaded (and detached) between postback requests.

You should not re-load (or refresh) the account on postback requests.

These should be sufficient to raise a OptimisticLockException.

If you want mutual exclusion on load instead on save, use a PessimisticLock. In this case only the first user gets access to the account page, the second one will get a PessimisticLockException.

---

based on your comments, use [ListConverter](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/converters/ListConverter) / [ListIndexConverter](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/converters/ListIndexConverter) or make your own converter extends [ValueChangeConverter](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/converters/ValueChangeConverter) to avoid converter reloads.

---

**UPDATE**

first of all, make sure of this:

```
@Named(value = "mouvementBean")
@ViewScoped
public class MouvementBean implements Serializable 
{
    public class MouvementBean()
    {
        // log your bean creation to verify that it's not re-instantiated on postback:
        // in some situation CDI annotations like @javax.inject.Named
        // are not compatible with @javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped and your bean becomes
        // RequestScoped. I don't think this is the case, but double check it. And if you
        // don't need CDI just stick with @javax.faces.ManagedBean
    }
}
```

second, `f:viewParam` is executed on postback too! so either use `o:viewParam` (OmniFaces, again :D) or try with a straightforward `@PostConstruct` solution (and **remove** `f:viewParam` from page):

```
@Named(value = "mouvementBean")
@ViewScoped
public class MouvementBean implements Serializable 
{
    @EJB
    private GestionnaireDeCompteBancaire gestionnaireDeCompteBancaire;

    private CompteBancaire compteBancaire;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init()
    {
        FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

        // OmniFaces, again and again :)
        // String stringId = Faces.getRequestParameter("id");
        String stringId = facesContext.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("id");

        long id = NumberUtils.toLong(stringId);

        compteBancaire = gestionnaireDeCompteBancaire.getById(id);

        // or you can do it with converter. But, generally, it's not a good practice to instance converters on your own, like you do
        // in ModifierBean.getConverter(). Create a standalone converter class that implements javax.faces.convert.Converter and 
        // register it with @FacesConverter("compteConverter"), so you can delegate instantiation to Application
        //
        // Application application = facesContext.getApplication();
        //
        // compteBancaire = (CompteBancaire) application.createConverter("compteConverter").getAsObject(facesContext, null, stringId);
    }
}
```

third, even if it actually works, you declare `f:metadata` in a wrong position. The correct position is this (`f:metadata` doesn't need to be 'included', it's not a regular component):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      ...>

    <f:metadata>
        <f:viewParam name="id" value="#{mouvementBean.compteBancaire}"
            converter="#{modifierBean.converter}" />
    </f:metadata>

    <ui:composition template="./template.xhtml">
        <ui:param name="soustitre" 
            value="Ajouter/retirer de l'argent sur le compte de #{mouvementBean.compteBancaire.nom}"/>

        ...
    </ui:composition>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, I was wrong; in fact the converter is launched during the validation phase (I have added a phaseListener to know that). In the JSF page I use EL expressions like #{bean.amount} where the owner of the account is not mentioned so I don't understand why the converter (for the owner of the account) is launched during the validation phase. In this converter there is the code that load the owner to convert the id into a owner. In the JSF page there is a viewParam that uses the converter, which put the owner into a property of the backing bean (whose scope is view).

Comment: The problem comes from the reload of the converter to convert an id into an owner of an account. if another user has modified the account, the new version number of the account is loaded at this moment by the converter.

Comment: Thanks for your help Michele. I will try OmniFaces to see if it solves the problem but I would like to find a solution without it. I have find another way to do by removing the converter and by replacing it by a <f:viewAction> which load the account using the id of the account (the same code as for the converter). The OptimisticLockException is thrown. However I will be satisfied only when I understand why the converter is launched during the validation phase. If I had the code of the page and the bean, could you quickly read it to try to understand?

Comment: I strongly recommend OmniFaces, it's a masterpiece. I use it very extensively. Converters are invoked during validation to allow validators to handle Objects instead of Strings. See [this article](http://palkonyves.blogspot.it/2013/08/demistifying-jsf-21-lifecycle-mojarra.html) for a full analysis, images in particular. Post your code, I'll try to give it a shot :)

Comment: Yes I know it is a very good library written by very good programmers but I have a principle: stay in the standards if it is possible. In this particular case my solution is simple and works. Perhaps I will use that library for another occasion.

Comment: Thanks Michele for giving a shot to my code if you have time. I hope you will discover an obvious error that I missed.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Michele for your update. "f:viewParam is executed on postback too" was what I missed. As `<f:viewParam>` is considered as an input component, its value is convertered and validated in the validation phase of the life cycle of JSF.

I mark your answer as a good answer but I write this other answer to summarize our discussion for the future readers and to tell them there is also another solution.

So, there is 2 ways to solve my problem:

- solution 1: the solution you explain in the update of your answer (I haven't tested it yet).
- solution 2: use a `<f:viewAction>` instead of the converter, as I explained before. In the code I gave in my question you have just to remove `<f:converter>` and to add `<f:viewAction>` in the metadata to call the code that convert an id (a long) into a CompteBancaire. You also have to add a property for the id in the backing bean.

Solution 2 needs a viewscope for the backing bean to keep the value of the variable compteBancaire. I don't know if it is necessary for your solution. With my first code (the one which is in my question and which had a problem with concurrency) a request scope was sufficient (in my code you can replace `@ViewScoped` by `@RequestScoped` because the variable `compteBancaire` is initialized by the converter).

About your remarks:

I don't think f:metadata is in the wrong position. I use a template which contains a place (`<ui:insert>`) for metadata. In the pages which use the template, f:metadata will be in the good place (exactly like in the code you give in example).

I don't use `@javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped`; I use `@javax.faces.view.ViewScoped` from CDI so I don't think there could be a problem with `@Named`.

Why do you say that using a method to return a converter is not good? What type of problem could I have with this way of doing? Often I use a standalone class for a converter but returning a converter in a method facilitates the injection of an EJB (with `@EJB`).

Answer (score -1):

Since this is bank account money, you need to have a very reliable solution. Maybe the best solution would be implementing long running transaction with locking the row in database so that anyone would not be able to select this row for updating. I mean on ui this would look bad to see message like "someone update the data blabla" which can occur if you implement optimistic lock approach. You should not allow user to see the page where he could update data at the time when someone else is updating this data.
Or if you choose optimistic locking then you will have to store the state of the object on server only in stateful bean (session) and implement retry logic to make all the checks necessary for payment or etc. and retry updating the object again with new version number. Also do not forget that all db updates should be in one transaction or you can get bad data. Use spring transactional annotations.